# Where is the space causing the outer scroll bar coming from?

Tags: html, css, whitespace, removing-whitespace

In this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LgX7u/1/ You can see that there are two scroll bars. I think there should only be one, the inside one that is part of `#b`, and I'm trying to figure out how to get it to look that way (without just making the outer scrollbar invisible or something).

The extra space that is causing the outer scroll bar is caused by some kind of white space. If you set `font-size: 0`, then it disappears and works properly and there's only one scrollbar. I do not want to rely on that behavior though, I am wondering where the white space is coming from. I can't see where since there are no spaces between the `div`s.

I also do not want to use `float` because it is not applicable to my real situation.

**Edit**

Here is a better example of what I really have if the other one is too vague: http://jsfiddle.net/LgX7u/11/ (use a web inspector to see the other `.a` off the edge to the right).

Answer (score 3):

Remove this class:

```
div {
    height:100%;
}
```

The updated [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LgX7u/4/)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that because it reflects what I have to do in my real situation. All the CSS I wrote is to reflect my actual code, I didn't add any just for fun. Also, that doesn't fix the problem anyway, there's still space at the end if you scroll all the way down.

Comment: @uk4321 Is overflow:hidden; an option or will it affect the layout?

Comment: Yes, for some reason when I add `overflow:hidden` to the `#a` in my real code, it actually doesn't hide anything, it removes the scroll bar from the `#b` and adds it to the `html` element, which messes everything up obviously. I wish I knew why it did that but I'm not a CSS guru. If you know why it does that and know how to work around it then that will answer my question too.

Comment: @uk4321 Could you put a bigger section of your HMTL and CSS into another Fiddle for us to get a better picture of your problem?

Comment: Here is a better approximation: http://jsfiddle.net/LgX7u/11/ If you use a web inspector you can see the second `.b` off the screen to the right, which is how I need it (I will scroll with JS). Sorry for the wrapper1 wrapper2 wrapper3, those are not named that way in my real code, they contain other things as well, not just one element each. I went through all those contortions with `display: table` because I am trying to have full screen divs stack horizontally and they don't stack horizontally if I use float no matter what (I spent a long time trying). So that's what I have, hope it helps.

Comment: I set the second .b to position:absolute and it fixed it.

Comment: Ah sorry, I will have an unlimited and unknown number of those `.b` at runtime added with JS. I think `position: absolute` only works for two (or maybe I tried it wrong).

Comment: Somehow there is whitespace being generated, where does it come from?

Comment: Okay, this will work now: remove display:table-row; from #wrapper2.

Comment: Actually that scroll bar is on the iframe, not the `.b` which is where I need it to be.